# Display SQLITE output in column rather than row

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

At the moment I have the below script which auto generates the table names and row data automatically by looking at a sqlite table. So regardless of if you have 2 or 10 columns this script works.

At the moment the script outputs the results like this:

> [image]
>
> *Output currently appears as a Row*

I have tried altering the script so that it outputs the results like below. Can someone assist or guide me in the right direction to achieve this?

Is it possible to output the results of the query in the below format: going down in a column rather than across as a row ?

> [image]
>
> *Output should appear as a Column*

```
<?
    $ED = $_GET['ED'];
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $table_name = $_GET['table'];
?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
    
    <table>
    <?php // Display all sqlite column names for chosen table

    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info($table_name)");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {

if ($table['name'] == "ID") {

        echo "<tr><td>" . $table['name'] . "</td></tr>";
    
} else {
    
        $table_name_header = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', $table['name'])));
        echo "<tr><td>" . $table_name_header . "</td></tr>";
        } 

        
}
?>

    </table>
    
    </td>
    <td>
<table>
<?

    
// Display all sqlite data for chosen table

    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info($table_name)");

    $columns = array();

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $columns[] = $table['name'];
    }

    // Display * from USERS

    
//    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE ID = "57"');
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ID = "' . $ID . '"');
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
//          echo "<tr>";
            $test = $row[0];
        foreach ($columns as $col) 

            echo "<tr><td>" . $row[$col] . "</td></tr>";
            
    }
//          echo "</tr>";
?>
</table>
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Build the html by hand first. That'll tell you how to build the PHP to generate that HTML.

Comment: Also your code is prone to SQL injection. And you should not use short open tags for example code here on Stackoverflow. And you should not post live-code examples but instead re-create a (smaller) example from scratch that demonstrates your issue and is self-containing (e.g. it's most likely not because of the database, but just the loop, so an example could work containing the data showing the problem).

Comment: Hint: You will need to fetch all data first and store it temporarily into a variable to change from rows (as in the database) to columns (as in the HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the code to the below by putting the data into an combined array and then pulling it back via a loop it will display as required:

```
<?


// Display all sqlite data for chosen table

    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info($table_name)");

    $columns = array();

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $columns[] = $table['name'];

    }

    // Display * from USERS


//    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE ID = "57"');
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ID = "' . $ID . '"');
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
//          echo "<tr>";
            $test = $row[0];
        foreach ($columns as $col) 
        $column_data[] = $row[$col];

//            echo "<tr><td>" . $row[$col] . "</td></tr>";

    }
//          echo "</tr>";
?>

<?
$array = $columns;
$array2 = $column_data;

$result = array_combine($array, $array2);
//print_r($result);
?><br><br>
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" color="#4B708D">
<thead>
<?
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
  echo "<tr><td bgcolor='#c6d5e1'>$key</td><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>$value</td></tr>";
}
?>
</thead>
</table>
```